# 3x3 array mutiplication in c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm not sure what I went wrong, my code doesn't seem to work with anything else beside single integer. Am trying to get 3x3 array and find its determinant and work out its inverse function and then do the multiplication to get I.

```
//matrix product
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            product[i][j] += array[i][k] * invertA[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

... Below is the array from user input

```
int main() {

int array[3][3], invertA[3][3], product[3][3], i, j, k;  // The global scope 
// ask for input    
printf("Please enter 9 elements of the matrix seperated by a space: \n");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  //the loop - create a table of 3 x 3 
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);   //save user-input as integer (%d) into the matrix a[i][j]
    }
}
```

and the other array is from code

```
//a11 a12 a13 
invertA[0][0] = (array[1][1] * array[2][2] - array[2][1] * array[1][2]) / determinant;
invertA[0][1] = -(array[1][0] * array[2][2] - array[1][2] * array[2][0]) / determinant;
invertA[0][2] = (array[1][0] * array[2][1] - array[2][0] * array[1][1]) / determinant;
    //a21 a22 a23
invertA[1][0] = -(array[0][1] * array[2][2] - array[0][2] * array[2][1]) / determinant;
invertA[1][1] = (array[0][0] * array[2][2] - array[0][2] * array[2][0]) / determinant;
invertA[1][2] = -(array[0][0] * array[2][1] - array[2][0] * array[0][1]) / determinant;
       //a31 a32 a33
invertA[2][0] = (array[0][1] * array[1][2] - array[0][2] * array[1][1]) / determinant;
invertA[2][1] = -(array[0][0] * array[1][2] - array[1][0] * array[0][2]) / determinant;
invertA[2][2] = (array[0][0] * array[1][1] - array[1][0] * array[0][1]) / determinant;
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `product[3][3]` --> `product[3][3] = {{0}}`

Comment: `// The global scope` -- um, pardon?

Comment: You have to zero-initialize `product` like BLUEPIXY said. I assume this is for a learning experience but if you really want to work with matrices seriously I'd recommend the Eigen library http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/

Comment: You divide by the determinant but have not indicated how that is calculated. And are integer values and arithmetic adequate?